# Changing div background image refreshes page

Tags: javascript, background, setinterval

I have a section that overlaps another section.  When i change the background image using setinterval, the background image appears on top and then the other section eventually appears.  It looks like the entire page is refreshed.  I need to refresh a background image on a section on an interval without refreshing the remainder of the page.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code, the picture.jpg does not disappear:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="bg" height="400" style="background-image:url(red.jpg);">
<div>
<img src="picture.jpg">
</div>
</div>

<script>
setInterval(function(){
   document.getElementById("bg").style.backgroundImage = (document.getElementById("bg").currentStyle.backgroundImage.search('red.jpg') < 0)
                                                       ? "url(red.jpg)"
                                                       : "url(blue.jpg)";
   }, 3000);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```